# How to do something functionally with all the elements of a list in Perl 6?

Tags: raku

For example I have an `Array` with numbers:

```perl6
> my @a = ^5
[0 1 2 3 4]
```

and I want to print their squares. I can use `map`, but it will also return a modified `List` (these five `True`s), which I don't want:

```perl6
> @a.map({ put $_**2 })
0
1
4
9
16
(True True True True True)
```

The only way I've found is to use `hyper >>`:

```perl6
> @a>>.&{ put $_**2 }
0
1
4
9
16
```

but

- the syntax is a bit clumsy (probably I don't do it as supposed)
- what if I don't want it to work with `hyper`?

So what is the right way to do it?

P.S. Of course, I can use `map` and then `put` the result:

```perl6
.put for @a.map: {$_**2 }
```

but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `map` is fine for this purpose, since in sink context it will not produce a result list. In the REPL, the result of the `map` is wanted, thus why it is produced. But in a case like:

```
@a.map({ put $_**2 });
say "That's all, folks";
```

Then the result of the `map` is not wanted, and so no list of results will be assembled. If wishing to really spell this out, it's possible to write:

```
sink @a.map({ put $_**2 })
```

Be aware that the last statement in a routine is taken as an implicit return value. Using `--> Nil` will suffice to ensure a final `map` is in sink context instead.

```
sub put-squares(@a --> Nil) {
    @a.map({ put $_**2 })
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This answer is complementary to the other answers. I'll wander around your question on the assumption that you and other readers are interested in some possibilities of an FP*ish* approach that eschews purism.

```
my @a = ^5;            # @a bound to an Array
@a.map(* ** 2)  .put;  # 0 1 4 9 16
@a.put;                # 0 1 2 3 4       <- Array unchanged

@a.map(* **= 2) .put;  # 0 1 4 9 16
@a.put;                # 0 1 4 9 16      <- Array changed

@a := @a.List;         # rebind @a to a List
@a.map(* ** 2)  .put;  # 0 1 16 81 256   <- Same as if Array
@a.put;                # 0 1 4 9 16      <- List unchanged

@a.map(* **= 2) .put;  # Cannot assign to an immutable value
```

The `Array` examples show how you *can* optionally mutate en passant. (It does so using a binary (infix) op in the form `op=` instead of just `op` but if that's confusing just note the effect and ignore the syntax.)

En passant mutation is a much more "evil" side effect than mere `.put`ing, such that a purist would be kinda *horrified* if someone called it "functional" style. Not me of course. :)

And the `List` example goes in the other direction, moving toward immutability. `List`s are immutable [wannabes](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Wannabe).

Again, those into FP will likely laud their immutability. Purists will denigrate the wannabe aspect. Perl folk will likely see it both ways.

## Immutable wannabes

A `List` is either entirely or mostly immutable.

You can never push or pop a `List`.

It's length is always immutable.

A list of basic values is fully immutable:

```
my $really-immutable-list = (1,2,'foo', 1.5, (3,4,5));
```

The exception is that if an element of a list is itself mutable then you can mutate it and thus mutate the `List`:

```
my $only-shallowly-immutable-list = (1,2,'foo', 1.5, [3,4,5]);
$only-shallowly-immutable-list[4][1] = 9;
say $only-shallowly-immutable-list; # (1 2 foo 1.5 [3 9 5])
```

More subtly:

```
class c { has $.foo; method waldo { $!foo = 42 } }
my $bar  = c.new;
my $list = ($bar, 2);
say $list;   # (c.new(foo => Any) 2)
$bar.waldo; 
say $list;   # (c.new(foo => 42) 2)
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, using `>>.` is **not** a good idea, as the *order* in which the operations are performed, is *not* guaranteed to be in any specific order.

You could use a `WhateverCode`:

```
.say for @a.map: * ** 2
```

which I personally find most readable.  Alternately, you could use a placeholder variable:

```
.say for @a.map: { $^value ** 2 }
```

or write it out completely:

```
.say for @a.map: { $_ ** 2 }
```

But apparently you don't want that.  Why?

Comment: Suppose I already have a function whose side-effects are important for me and which has no (meaningful) return value. In my example it was `my &func = { put $^x ** 2 }`. What is the right way to apply it to all the elements of a list using `method` syntax. I.e. how to achieve what `>>.` does without using `hyper`?